# PLpgSQL INSERT-RETURNING-INTO bug at PostgreSQL v12.6?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, plpgsql

The command `INSERT ... RETURNING c1 INTO v1` for a declared PLpgSQL variable is losing value on a second use.

In the complete function below, the "v1" variable is `q_file_id`: it have a non-zero value at the first INSERT (`jins`) but, seems that its value is not the same in the second INSERT (`ins2`), or data dependency is not recognized.

```sql
CREATE or replace FUNCTION ingest.geojson_load(
    p_file text, p_ftid int, p_ftype text DEFAULT NULL
) RETURNS text AS $f$
 DECLARE
    q_file_id integer;
    q_ret text;
 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO ingest.file(ftid,file_type,file_meta)
     SELECT p_ftid::smallint,
            COALESCE( p_ftype, substring(p_file from '[^\.]+$') ),
            geojson_readfile_headers(p_file)
  RETURNING file_id INTO q_file_id;
  RAISE NOTICE 'The File_id is %', q_file_id;

  WITH jins AS ( -- FIRST use is working fine!
    INSERT INTO ingest.tmp_geojson_feature
     SELECT * 
     FROM geojson_readfile_features_jgeom(p_file, q_file_id )
    RETURNING 1
   ), ins2 AS ( -- bug at this SECOND use of q_file_id
    INSERT INTO ingest.feature
     SELECT file_id, feature_id, properties, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(jgeom)
     FROM ingest.tmp_geojson_feature
     WHERE file_id = q_file_id
    RETURNING 1
   )
   SELECT 'Hello jins='|| (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jins) 
         ||' items from file_id '|| q_file_id ||'.'
         ||E'\n ins2= '|| (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ins2) ||' items.'
         INTO q_ret;
  -- if no bug: DELETE FROM ingest.tmp_geojson_feature WHERE file_id = q_file_id;
  RETURN q_ret;
 END;
$f$ LANGUAGE PLpgSQL;
```

---

**Bug evidence**: the function says "Hello... ins2=0", but when the RAISE NOTICE is 8 and I run only the INSERT fragment ins2 with 8, it is working fine.

```sql
    INSERT INTO ingest.feature
     SELECT file_id, feature_id, properties, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(jgeom)
     FROM ingest.tmp_geojson_feature
     WHERE file_id = 8
   -- inserted!
```

### NOTES

Looking back at the function with this evidence in mind, the first INSERT was separated to avoid execution concurrency, so a natural solution is also to split the WITH statement into a sequence of two INSERTS...But **the question here is not "how to avoid the problem"**, is about *Why* (?) [PostgreSQL *planner/optimizer*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-optimizer.html)  is not optimizing the "dataflow of INSERTs" of the WITH clause.

We can imagine that *planner* do the split under the hood, or recognizes
the *data pipeline* and check the opportunity of a kind of *pipeline concurrency* — splitting the two INSERTs into stages to use a [stream processing strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_processing).

---

(EDITED after @LaurenzAlbe's answer)

PS: the "dataflow of INSERTs" can be optimized. [Big data streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_processing) and [small execution pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining)  are popular optimization strategies, using the same concept. It is present in dataflow applications and many languages, like [Go](https://towardsdatascience.com/concurrent-data-pipelines-in-golang-85b18c2eecc2), [Scala](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/Pipeline.html), ... or frameworks like [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html).

Perhaps is natural for an expert to say "there are no data dependency to be  recognized"... So, in the case that it is not a PostgreSQL's bug (maybe my [wrong hypothesis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250659/205446) leading to a wrong question), a sub-question is 
*"How to say to PostgreSQL planner that there is an optimization (pipeline) opportunity, is possible?"*; or *"Why the planner is not using this kind of optimization opportunity?"*

Answer (score 2):

As is to be expected, the bug is yours. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

> The sub-statements in `WITH` are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in `WITH`, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see [Chapter 13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html)), so they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables. This alleviates the effects of the unpredictability of the actual order of row updates, and means that `RETURNING` data is the only way to communicate changes between different `WITH` sub-statements and the main query.

Your misconception seems to be that SQL is a procedural language, where certain parts of a statement are executed in a certain order.  But SQL isn't, and you cannot depend on that.

The remedy is simple: use two separate SQL statements, then the second one can see the effects of the first.

Comment: Hi, interesting and good clues. But not make sense: PLpgSQL is a sequential language, and the sequence of steps is: 1. "INSERT INTO ...RETURNING file_id INTO q_file_id"; 2. RAISE NOTICE q_file_id"; 3. "WITH ... using q_file_id". So `q_file_id` **must** be the  same for all WITH statement.

Comment: ... hum... The second INSERT depends on the first INSERT, ok, but I need a [pipeline INSERT execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining), it is good to optimize, each INSERT as a CPU processes...  PostgreSQL **optimizer must to detect** that there are a "dataflow dependency" (can't be a full-parallel process it is only-pipeline-level of concurrency) . So the question is **"make sense?"**. If the answer is affirmative we conclude that it is a bug; else (if my interpretation is wrong) it is my fail.

Comment: You are throwing big words around, but this has nothing to do with CPU implementation. Sure, PostgreSQL could work differently, but then it need not. I don't see the problem - run two different SQL statements.

Comment: Hi, sorry to use the term "CPU", it's not about "CPU scale", and I'm not an expert on *database concurrency*... In the PostgreSQL universe, the correct jargon it is perhaps "snapshot" (or "thread" or "parallel transaction" ...). The focus in my comment is *pipe parallelism* (a scale-independent concept), then a sub-question is "Why doesn't PostgreSQL use pipelines?".

Comment: You are basically complaining because PostgreSQL works differently than you wish. "Why" questions are mostly useless: the answer invariably is "because it was designed / implemented differently". Either do things the PostgreSQL way or use a different database.